# Is fprintf() function set errno for its error indication?

Tags: c

I have seen that many library functions as `printf, recv, send, strtol, socket` and many others set `errno` value to indicate its appropriate error. I have searched for fprintf() in man page as well as on internet but I don't find anything clear. So please, help me to clear my doubt.

I want to know if fprintf() uses errno to indicate its error?

Comment: Why not read the manual page?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) for an explanation of fprintf(). Basically it indicates an error thru the return value and not errno: "On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned."

Comment: `printf` doesn't set `errno`, it only returns a negative number.

Comment: @EdHeal At manual page it is written that "if any output error encountered it return negative value." But nothing about "errno". Help..

Comment: @deanware I have go through link. What does it means "If a multibyte character encoding error occurs while writing wide characters, errno is set to EILSEQ and a negative number is returned."

Comment: Ok fine I have got it.... Thanks to all of you..

Comment: @Shiv - It also does not mention that there will be a stiff wind from the north. Therefore one can conclude that the `errno` is not affect nor is the north wind

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry... But I was little bit confused.

Comment: @EdHeal Functions setting `errno` explicitly state so in "RETURN VALUE" section of their manpage. E.g. `read(2)` says "On  error,  -1  is  returned, and errno is set appropriately." so the snarky comment was neither funny nor correct.

Comment: @rootkea that is exactly the point. In the return section of any man page, if `errno` is set, or a further inquiry with `ferror()` is required, the man page will so state. If the man page is silent, you can make no presumption about `errno`. So Ed's comment is precisely on point, *Read the man page*. It's the difference between teaching a man to fish and feeding him for life, or giving a man a fish and feeding him for a day.... If further reading is desired, the Primary Authority is the C standard [7.21.6.1 The fprintf function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was replying to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293809/is-fprintf-function-set-errno-for-its-error-indication?noredirect=1#comment60213241_36293809 (which unnecessarily brought "north wind" instead of answering in clear-cut way) and not the one asking to read the manpage.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the terseness. Reading Ed's first comment, I really couldn't see how that generated your comment.

Comment: @rootkea You need to be careful with `errno`.  Especially in this case.  Per [**7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**, paragraph 3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3) of the C11 (draft...) standard: "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  Since `fprintf()` is not documented to set `errno`, it's free to munge `errno` to anything it feels like.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `errno` by `fprintf()` is *not* specified by the C standard.

Some compilers do create code that sets `errno` to the value of `ERANGE` to indicate out of range (overflow) or to other values.  Recall the C standard only specifies a few: `EDOM`, `EILSEQ`, `ERANGE`.

Concerning the return value of `fprintf()`:

> The `fprintf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred. C11 §7.21.6.1 14

```
if (fprintf(ostream, ...) < 0) {
  Handle_Error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I want to know if fprintf() uses errno to indicate its error?
```

No it does not use `errno` to indicate an error.

It does use it's return value to indicate what happened and you can find out what that errno means. If you're on Linux have a look at `explain_fprintf`

http://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_fprintf

> The explain_fprintf function is used to obtain an explanation of an error returned by the fprintf(3) system call. The least the message
> will contain is the value of strerror(errno), but usually it will do
> much better, and indicate the underlying cause in more detail.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The other answer does.

Comment: @rootkea I've edited the answer to explicitly say that it does use an errno in the first sentence

Comment: But that's the thing. Setting `errno` by `fprintf()` is **not** specified by the C standard. See the other answer.

Comment: @rootkea You're right, question corrected to say it does not use `errno`